# Stop visual from showing if a column has been filtered and also in the table

Tags: filter, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have come across a caveat of using `ISFILTERED` when the column you are checking is also within that main table.

Lets say I have a table that has two columns, one called `Campaign` and the other called `margin`.

I have a `Campaign slicer` and I want to show the table only when specifically that slicer has been filtered, however, this does not work as a visual level filter as the `Campaign` column is also within the table so in essence it is already in context filtering the table.

So even though the DAX code will return 0 in the card visual, the table will still be visible.

[image]

Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like so:

```
Is Filtered = IF(CALCULATE(ISFILTERED('YourTable'), ALLSELECTED('YourTable')), "yes")
```